# Can the following IF formulas be converted into a formula involving only the min and max functions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been learning that certain IF statements can be converted into a form that involves only max/min.
Some examples include:

```
IF ( x > y , x , y ) === MAX ( x , y )

IF ( x < 0 , x , 0 ) === MIN ( x , 0 )

IF ( x * y > L, L, x * y ) === MIN ( x * y, min_value )
```

One more complicated example includes:

```
IF ( IF (x > y , x , y) > z , z , IF (x > y , x , y )) ===  MIN ( MAX ( x , y ) , z )
```

Consider the following excel formulas,

```
IF ( x > y , x , 0 )
```

or

```
IF ( x < y , x , 0 )
```

Can the following formulas be converted into a form involving only max and min? If not, is there a process that I can use to deduce that an if statement cannot be converted into this form?

Comment: Please put your data so that we can check your algorithm is correct or not.

Comment: I do not have any data. I just wanted to know if the 2 formulas above can be written using only max and min.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge.

`IF ( x > y , x , y ) === MAX ( x , y )` is basically what `MAX` may be doing behind the scenes. I don't think `IF ( x < y , x , 0 )` can be accomplished with `MAX`, because `MAX` only returns the same arguments that it calculates, whereas `IF` returns other values (which you can supply with the compared values, as you did)